# Transfer list size from Activity to Adapter class and update TextView with that quantity

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have a method in my `FollowersActivity` class `getFriendsAttendingEvent();` which returns the number of users that adhere to two specific criteria. Now, those users populate a list when I click on a `TextView` which I have in my Adapter class `PostAdapter`.

I need to get that number (quantity) of users that are in the list and I want to put it in the `TextView` in my `PostAdapter` class. I want to do something like `holder.textView.setText(*list.size())`, but how can I get that number from my `FollowersActivity` over to my `PostAdapter` class?

I know from the Adapter class I transfer data between the two classes by using `Intent`, but to go the other way around, would I have to create an interface or something? SharedPreferences perhaps? I don't know...

**How would I send this line, `String number = String.valueOf(mIdList.size());` over to my `PostAdapter`? This is the number that I need.**

**FollowersActivity**

```
private void getFriendsAttendingEvent() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Event").child(mPostId);
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mIdList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mIdList.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }

                DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Following").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
                reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        mIdList1.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            for (String id : mIdList) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                                    if (Objects.equals(snapshot.getKey(), id)) {
                                        mIdList1.add(snapshot.getKey());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (mIdList1.size() > 0) {
                        String number = String.valueOf(mIdList.size());
                        Log.d("NUMBEROFUSERS", number);
                        showUsers();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**PostAdapter**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        final Post post = mPost.get(position);

        holder.friendsAttendingEvent.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FollowersActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", post.getPostid());
            intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());
            intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
            intent.putExtra("title", "Friends Attending");
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I have understood so far is that,

You have a `PostAdapter` (that displays data related to a post just like in most of the social media applications) and this Adapter has a `TextView` that represents the number of followers.

So, the navigation structure might be like this:

`PostAdpater` --- (Click on the `TextView`) ---> `FollowersActivity`

By Clicking the `TextView` representing the number of followers we shift to the `FollowersActivity`, and there you might be displaying the details of Followers. But the problem is, that you are fetching the data on the `FollowersActivity` where as you required it before the navigation on the `PostAdapter`.

The Only Simple Solution that I am able to figure out is that you move your query function `getFriendsAttendingEvent()` from `FollowersActivity` to `PostAdapter`, fetch the count of followers in the adapter and then pass that count to the `FollowersActivity` through Intent in case you do not want to re fetch data.

```
      PostAdapter         ------->         FollowersActivity
 (count required here)                      (fetching here)

      PostAdapter         ------->         FollowersActivity
  (fetch count here)         (pass data here through Intent of refetch it)
```

Please tell me if didn't understood the problem correctly i might come up with a better solution

Comment: Hey, yes you understood correctly: ```PostAdapter ---> TextView ---> FollowersActivity```. Then in ```FollowersActivity``` I write the methods to get the user's information, and then I need the **number** from the list in ```FollowersActivity``` to show it in the UI. I actually thought about moving the method from ```FollowersActivity``` to ```PostAdapter```, but then I thought there might be an easier way to transfer data... You think I should move the method as opposed to transferring the **number** from ```FollowersActivity``` to ```PostAdapter``` somehow?

Comment: Don't You need the count before moving to the `FollowersActivity`, I think that the user will click on the count displayed in the `TextView` but you fetch the count after moving to the FollowersActivity, event if you return the count from FollowersActivity to PostAdapter will it still make sense. If you still want this than you can return the count as ActivityResultCode since it is number (read more about ActivityResult), moreover shared preferences can be used or static varaibles can also be used. But i will stick to the previous solution since it is more reliable (and professional).

Comment: Thanks for the tips man. I rewrote the method in the Adapter class and works just fine. I will definitely read about ActivityResult !! Thanks for the advice!